# Leer un archivo en java

Tags: java

Estoy tratando de leer un archivo txt donde le coloque un do while para que cuando empiece a leer la primera linea pueda actualizarse en el sp que mando a llamar despues pero se cicla no entiendo porque se cicla Lo que quiero hacer es que empiece a leer linea por linea el archivo mientras que lee una linea se va a ejecutar al sp donde el sp es donde empieza a insertar la informacion me pueden ayudar a resolverlo.

```
public class Ciudad {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    int li_region = 0;
    FileReader fr = null;
    BufferedReader br = null;
    File archivo = null;
    Connection oCon = null;
    li_region = Integer.valueOf(args[0]).intValue();
    //int ln_codigo = 0;
    //String lv_mensaje = "Proceso Exitoso";


    //Obtenemos la fecha del sistema
    Fecha Fecha = new Fecha();
    System.out.println("Today : " + Fecha.today);

          try {
             // Apertura del fichero y creacion de BufferedReader para leer
             archivo = new File ("/siapgsmtmp/catalogo_poblaciones/POBLACIONES_SIAP_"+Fecha.today+"_R"+li_region+".txt");
             fr = new FileReader (archivo);
             br = new BufferedReader(fr);

         // Conexion a BD parametro a la region 
             BD_SIAP BD_SIAP = new BD_SIAP();
             oCon = BD_SIAP.get_conection(li_region);


         // Lectura del fichero
            String cadena = null;
            do
            {
              cadena=br.readLine();
              System.out.println(cadena);

                 //executeSP(linea);

                String commandText = "{call SP_CIUDAD_ADM_SINC(?, ?, ?)}";
                CallableStatement stmt = oCon.prepareCall(commandText);
                stmt.setObject(1, cadena);
                stmt.registerOutParameter(2, Types.NUMERIC);
                stmt.registerOutParameter(3, Types.VARCHAR);
                stmt.execute();
                System.out.println("Codigo: " + stmt.getInt(2));
                System.out.println("Mensaje : " + stmt.getString(3));
            }
                while(cadena.length()>0);
             }
          catch(Exception e){
             e.printStackTrace();
          }finally{
             // En el finally se cierra el fichero
             try{                    
                if( null != fr ){   
                   fr.close();     
                }                  
             }catch (Exception e2){ 
                e2.printStackTrace();
             }
          }
          try {
              oCon.close();
              oCon = null;
            } catch (SQLException e) {
              e.printStackTrace();
            }
    }
```

}

Answer (score 0):

Hola @Fanny Hernandez Ramirez.
Primero que nada hay que cambiar el bucle por que primero se ejecuta el sp y luego hace la validación, lo cual no creo que sea correcto, ya que cuando llegues a punto final del documento ejecutará el sp y después validara si contiene información o no, por lo tanto es mejor usar un **while** y no un **do while**.

```
   // Lectura del fichero
   while(br.readLine()!=null) {
              System.out.println(cadena); //Se imprime linea por línea
              //executeSP(linea);
                String commandText = "{call SP_CIUDAD_ADM_SINC(?, ?, ?)}";
                CallableStatement stmt = oCon.prepareCall(commandText);
                stmt.setObject(1, br.readLine());
                stmt.registerOutParameter(2, Types.NUMERIC);
                stmt.registerOutParameter(3, Types.VARCHAR);
                stmt.execute();
                System.out.println("Codigo: " + stmt.getInt(2));
                System.out.println("Mensaje : " + stmt.getString(3));
    }
    br.close(); //Cerramos el recurso.
```

Nota:Cambiamos la asignación de un **string** y solo usamos el metodo **readLine**, esto para optimizar.
**Saludos.**

Comment: De hecho lo que estoy viendo es que mi SP es el que lo esta ciclando el proceso no es el java creo que pasare todo mi SP a java